# Generic function that returns IEntity[E][S]: Generics two levels down

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to do something like the following, but it's giving me a compilation/type error.

```
interface IEntityLookup {
    [Entity.PERSON]: IPersonLookup
    [Entity.COMPANY]: ICompanyLookup
}

interface ISubEntity {
    [Entity.PERSON]: People
    [Entity.COMPANY]: Companies
}

function mapEntity<E extends Entity, S extends ISubEntity[E]>(
    entityType: E,
    subEntity: S
): IEntityLookup[E][S] | null {
    switch (entityType) {
        case Entity.PERSON:
            return mapPerson(subEntity)
        case Entity.Company:
            return mapCompany(subEntity)
    }
}
```

Specifically, look at the function `mapEntity`, I want to be able to return something like `IEntityLookup[E][S]`, is that possible in Typescript?

I leave the full definitions here:

```
enum Companies {
    TESLA = "tesla",
    MICROSOFT = "microsoft",
}

interface ITesla {
    id: string
    cars: number
}

interface IMicrosoft {
    id: string
    software: string
}

enum People {
    ELON_MUSK = "elon-musk",
    BILL_GATES = "bill-gates",
}

interface IElonMusk {
    id: string
    rockets: number
}

interface IBillGates {
    id: string
    windows_version: string
}


interface ICompanyLookup {
    [Companies.TESLA]: ITesla
    [Companies.MICROSOFT]: IMicrosoft
}

interface IPersonLookup {
    [People.ELON_MUSK]: IElonMusk
    [People.BILL_GATES]: IBillGates
}

function mapPerson<T extends People>(
    personType: T
): IPersonLookup[T] | null {
    switch (personType) {
        case People.ELON_MUSK:
            return {id: "1", rockets: 1000} as IPersonLookup[T]

        case People.BILL_GATES:
            return {id: "1", windows_version: "98"} as IPersonLookup[T]

        default:
            return null
    }
}

function mapCompany<T extends Companies>(
 companyType: T
): ICompanyLookup[T] | null {
    switch (companyType) {
        case Companies.TESLA:
            return {id: "1", cars: 1000} as ICompanyLookup[T]
        case Companies.MICROSOFT:
            return {id: "1", software: "98"} as ICompanyLookup[T]
        default:
            return null
    }
}

enum Entity {
    PERSON = "person",
    COMPANY = "company",
}

interface IEntityLookup {
    [Entity.PERSON]: IPersonLookup
    [Entity.COMPANY]: ICompanyLookup
}

interface ISubEntity {
    [Entity.PERSON]: People
    [Entity.COMPANY]: Companies
}

function mapEntity<E extends Entity, S extends ISubEntity[E]>(
    entityType: E,
    subEntity: S
): IEntityLookup[E][S] | null {
    switch (entityType) {
        case Entity.PERSON:
            return mapPerson(subEntity)
        case Entity.Company:
            return mapCompany(subEntity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps unrelated to the core question, but you can ditch the `as` assertions in `mapPerson` and `mapEntity` by creating a map and then returning a value from the map.  You also don't need the `null` because `personType` is always a `Person` so there is no chance that it won't be found.

```
function mapPerson<T extends People>(
    personType: T
): IPersonLookup[T] {
    const map: IPersonLookup = {
        [People.ELON_MUSK]: { id: "1", rockets: 1000 },
        [People.BILL_GATES]: { id: "1", windows_version: "98" }
    }
    return map[personType];
}
```

You are getting errors on `mapEntity` because as far as typescript is concerned, it's not an absolute guarantee that the entity `E` and the subEntity `S` match.  This is the error that you get when passing `subEntity` as an argument to `mapCompany` - even within the `case Entity.COMPANY` branch.

```
Argument of type 'S' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Companies'.
  Type 'ISubEntity[E]' is not assignable to type 'Companies'.
    Type 'Companies | People' is not assignable to type 'Companies'.
```

`E` could be the union of both entities, and we could do something really stupid like this:

```
mapEntity<Entity, People>(Entity.COMPANY, People.BILL_GATES);
```

Which would lead to us calling `mapCompany` with a `Person` instead of a `Company`.

It is honestly really hard to properly type this sort of thing.  What I came up with is based on a union of valid pairings.  We use a double-nested mapped type to access the entities and sub-entities.  Each one is indexed by `keyof` to flatten it.

```
type AllLookups = {
    [E in keyof IEntityLookup]: {
        [S in keyof IEntityLookup[E]]: {
            entity: E;
            subEntity: S;
            value: IEntityLookup[E][S];
        }
    }[keyof IEntityLookup[E]]
}[keyof IEntityLookup]
```

This evaluates to the union type:

```
type AllLookups = {
    entity: Entity.PERSON;
    subEntity: People.ELON_MUSK;
    value: IElonMusk;
} | {
    entity: Entity.PERSON;
    subEntity: People.BILL_GATES;
    value: IBillGates;
} | {
    entity: Entity.COMPANY;
    subEntity: Companies.TESLA;
    value: ITesla;
} | {
    ...;
}
```

To use this on our `mapEntities` function, we make the `subEntity` `S` the primary generic.  The second variable `T` pulls the members of the union which have this sub-entity.  We use `T` to get the entity type and the return type.

This gives us a very clean signature in terms of calling the function, where we get the exact return type and we get errors if the entity type and subEntity type don't match.

```
// error -- good!
mapEntity(Entity.COMPANY, People.BILL_GATES);
// returns IBillGates
mapEntity(Entity.PERSON, People.BILL_GATES);
// returns ITesla
mapEntity(Entity.COMPANY, Companies.TESLA);
```

But we **still** have to make assertions in the function body because narrowing a variable doesn't narrow the generic and narrowing one variable doesn't narrow the other.  So I don't know if this is really much of an improvement over what you had before.  It could possibly be better if `entityType` and `subEntity` were two properties on the same object and the `switch` was done without destructuring.

```
function mapEntity<S extends AllLookups['subEntity'], T extends AllLookups & { subEntity: S }>(
    entityType: T['entity'], subEntity: S
): T['value'] {
    switch (entityType) {
        case Entity.PERSON:
            return mapPerson(subEntity as People);
        case Entity.COMPANY:
            return mapCompany(subEntity as Companies);
        default:
            throw new Error("Invalid entity type " + entityType);
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/KWzERm)

Regarding `IEntityLookup[E][S]`, it is an error because `IEntityLookup[Entity]` is the union `IPersonLookup | ICompanyLookup` and you cannot index that union.  You would have to use a complicated mapping similar to the `AllLookups` in order to get the value for a sub-entity regardless of entity type.